# Windows 7 64, Eclipse 64, JDK 64 and specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, odbc

On Windows 7 64 bit machine, with Eclipse Kepler 64 bit, JDK6, I have this error:

SQL Error: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application 0 IM014

This Q&A unfortunately didn't help me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721702/windows-7-64-bit-odbc-drivers-for-ms-access-missing

"Target" was set to: `%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe` and "Start in" was set to: `%windir%\System32`

so, I changed it to:
"Target" to: `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` and "Start in" was set `%windir%\SysWOW64` and later to `%windir%\System32` - didn't work neither way.

I also had a look at this but the answer is not satisfying (installing 32 bit version of Java and STS) [64-bit Java can't access 32-bit MS Access database via ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220914/64-bit-java-cant-access-32-bit-ms-access-database-via-odbc?rq=1)

I tried to put the argument "-D32" in the VM arguments, but didn't help either.

Neither this one:
[Is there a Windows 7 ODBC driver for Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013837/is-there-a-windows-7-odbc-driver-for-access)

I read this as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362(v=vs.85).aspx

and this
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/097ff93d-20be-41ed-b318-dc51cca0b811/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application?forum=wcf

but those are instructions for Visual Studio, in Eclipse KEPLER for Java SE, I don't know where to find options they suggest (compiling options x86 vs. x64)

Trying to use this 
[architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810754/architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application)  without success. When I try to install 64 bit drivers it complains that I use 32 bit Office and therefore those drivers can't be installed. I installed 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components but I gained nothing that previously weren't on system already http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

I also read this one:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a4ddb239-64d8-4074-978c-45c30381c107/ssrs-2012-error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture?forum=sqlreportingservices

If I understood it properly, as I am using Windows 7 64 bit, with Eclipse Kepler 64 bit, JDK6, and Office Access 2007, I believe I should be using this:

Quote: To manage a data source that connects to a 32-bit driver under 64-bit platform, we use C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

What should I do in order to make it work (besides to install 32 bit Eclipse and 32 bit JVM
as OP finally did here ([64-bit Java can't access 32-bit MS Access database via ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220914/64-bit-java-cant-access-32-bit-ms-access-database-via-odbc?rq=1))

Comment: What version of Access do you have installed?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Access 2007 32 bit, whole Office (that I have) is 32 bit. If I had 64 bit, I could (probably) download 64 bit drivers for Office 2010 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: This advice may not help, but don't use Access. MySQL, PostgreSQL or even SQL Server would avoid this native code issue. Otherwise, you're stuck with a 32-bit java (which you can use as a temporary solution, or not).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I totally agree, but I follow a tutorial from book with accompanying code and Access database. I mean it is not like I MUST use this (especially because I am familiar with Oracle SQL), it's just that I paid for the book and I want to work out every single example (in this case whole chapter) from it. BTW I set it as temporary solution 32 bit JDK & Eclipse and of course it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 32-bit JRE in a 64 bit eclipse,

> goto "Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs",
>   then click "Add"

Then use this new 32-bit JRE a the target runtime for your "Access" project (under "run configuration").

Answer (score 0):

This should be the complete "solution" for this problem:

- Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Right Click then
  Properties then Shortcut tab, set "Target" to
  `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` and set "Start in" to
  `%windir%\System32`
- Download and install 32 bit JDK

Do what Elliot Frisch says:

- Go to "Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs", then click
  "Add"
- Then use this new 32-bit JRE a the target runtime for your "Access"
  project (under "run configuration").

And that's it.